# Evaluating $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{6}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

> Show that series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{6}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$$ converges by simplifying its sequence of partial sums and find its sum.

I don't have much detail but this all I have:

$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{6}{n(n+1)(n+2)}
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{6}{m(m+1)(m+2)}\\
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{3(m^2+3m)}{2(m+1)(m+2)}\\
&=\frac{3}{2}\\
\end{align}$$

I know, I don't have much but any help will do with the detail or is it right.

Comment: Notation is kind of sloppy.

Comment: This is a [telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 
\begin{gather*}
\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n(n+1)}-\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\right),
\end{gather*}
we have, by telescoping summation, 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^N\left(\frac{1}{n(n+1)}-\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n(n+1)}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n(n+1)}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{m=2}^{N+1}\frac{1}{m(m+1)}\quad \quad (m=n+1)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n(n+1)}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=2}^{N+1}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n=2}^N\frac{1}{n(n+1)}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=2}^{N}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{(N+1)(N+2)}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{(N+1)(N+2)}\right)\to \frac{1}{4}, \qquad \text{as } N\to\infty,
\end{align*}
from which we can infer that
\begin{gather*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{6}{n(n+1)(n+2)}=6\cdot\frac{1}{4}=3/2.
\end{gather*}

Comment: what is the sum is it 3/2?

Comment: Because $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{6}{n(n+1)(n+2)}:=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{6}{n(n+1)(n+2)},$ and $\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{6}{n(n+1)(n+2)}=6\cdot\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{(N+1)(N+2)}\right)=\frac{6}{4}\frac{N(N+3)}{(N+1)(N+2)}\to 3/2,$ as $N\to\infty.$

Comment: May I suggest you mention the telescopic aspect of the summation in your good answer ? Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, Yes, I have used telescopic aspect. And thanks a lot!

Comment: I know you did. I was just suggesting you mention it in your answer. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, I have made some modifications according to your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you ! It was a good answer; it is now even better !

Comment: it said to use partial sums

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{6}{n(n+1)(n+2)}
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{3}{n}+\frac{3}{n+2}-\frac{6}{n+1}\right)\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\left(3x^{n-1}+3x^{n+1}-{6x}^{n}\right)\,\mathrm dx\tag{2}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(3x^{n-1}+3x^{n+1}-{6x}^{n}\right)\,\mathrm dx\tag{3}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{3}{1-x}+\frac{3x^2}{1-x}-\frac{6x}{1-x}\,\mathrm dx\tag{4}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{3+3x^2-6x}{1-x}\right)\,\mathrm dx\tag{5}\\
&=3\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2-2x+1}{1-x}\,\mathrm dx\tag{6}\\
&=3\int_{0}^{1}{1-x}\,\mathrm dx\tag{7}\\
&=3\cdot\frac14\\
&=\frac32\\
\end{align}$$

> $$\large\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{6}{n(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac32\\$$

Comment: Sticking to your username, I see! Slick proof.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}x^{n - 1}={1 \over 1 -x}\ \imp\
\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{x^{n} \over n}=\int_{0}^{x}{\dd t \over 1 - t}
=-\ln\pars{1 -x}
$$

> $$
> \sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{x^{n + 1} \over n\pars{n + 1}}
> =-\int_{0}^{x}\ln\pars{1 - t}\,\dd t 
> =x + \pars{1 - x}\ln\pars{1 - x}
> $$

$$
\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n\pars{n + 1}\pars{n + 2}}
=\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{t + \pars{1 - t}\ln\pars{1 - t}}\,\dd t 
={1 \over 4}
$$

> $$\color{#66f}{\large%
> \sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{6 \over n\pars{n + 1}\pars{n + 2}}} 
> =6\times{1 \over 4}=\color{#66f}{\large{3 \over 2}}
> $$