# If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {6 \over n(n+3)}$ converges find its sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm guessing this is a duplicate but I don't understand the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053790/evaluating-sum-n-1-infty-frac6nn1n2) (which is very similar to mine). We have only gone over the nth term test and the ratio test in my class so far, so I am assuming I should be able to solve this problem with one of those.

So I tried the nth term test:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} {6 \over n(n+3)} = 0$

Which means that test is inconclusive

Now the ratio test:

$\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left|{6 \over (n+1)(n+4)} \cdot {n(n+3) \over 6}\right| \\
& = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left|{n^2 + 3 \over  n^2 + 5n +5}\right| \\
& = 1
\end{align}$

Which is also inconclusive? This is where I am stuck, and I also don't know how to sum that series if it is convergent since when I write the first few terms out I can't seem to find a pattern like I usually do in an infinite series.

$6[\frac 1 4 + \frac 1 {10} + \frac 1 {18} + \frac 1 {28} + ... ]$

a = ? r = ?

I probably messed the tests up somehow?

Comment: Hint: partial fractions decomposition.

Comment: Are you sure you start with $n=0$?

Comment: Oops, sorry n=1 is the starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have directly 
$$
\frac{6}{n\left(n+3\right)} \underset{+\infty)}{\sim}\frac{6}{n^2}
$$
The series $\displaystyle \sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges, so as your series.
To find the sum, can you find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such as
$$
\frac{1}{n\left(n+3\right)}=\frac{\alpha}{n}+\frac{\beta}{n+3}  \ \ \ ?
$$
And then calculate
$$
S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{6}{k\left(k+3\right)}
$$

Careful, your sum does not exist for $n=0$.

Comment: "*find its sum*"

Comment: He was also stuck to show it converges, relax

Answer (score 3):

As shown by others, your series converges. To find its sum we can always use our [favourite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2608542/what-is-the-sum-of-the-infinite-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac-1n4n2/2609801#2609801) alternative method of converting the sum into a double integral.

Noting that
$$\int_0^1 x^{n - 1} \, dx = \frac{1}{n} \quad \text{and} \quad \int_0^1 y^{n + 2} \, dy = \frac{1}{n + 3},$$
the sum can be written as
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{6}{n (n + 3)} &= 6 \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \int_0^1 \int_0^1 x^{n - 1} y^{n + 2} \, dx dy\\
&= 6 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \sum_{n = 1}^\infty x^{n - 1} y^{n + 2} \, dx dy \tag1\\
&= 6 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{y^2}{x} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty (xy)^n \, dx dy\\
&= 6 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{y^2}{x} \cdot \frac{xy}{1 - xy} \, dx dy \tag2\\
&= 6 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{y^3}{1 - xy} \, dx dy\\
&= -6 \int_0^1 y^2 \ln (1 - xy) \Big{|}_0^1 \, dy\\
&= -6 \int_0^1 y^2 \ln (1 - y) \, dy\\
&= 2 \int_0^1 \frac{1 - y^3}{1 - y} \, dy \tag3\\
&= 2 \int_0^1 (1 + y + y^2) \, dy \tag4\\
&= 2 \left [y + \frac{y^2}{2} + \frac{y^3}{3} \right ]_0^1\\
&= 2 \left (1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} \right )\\
&= \frac{11}{3}.
\end{align*}

**Explanations**

1. Interchanging the sum with the double integration.
2. Summing the series which is geometric.
3. Integrating by parts.
4. Using the factorisation $1 - y^3 = (1 - y)(1 + y + y^2)$.

Comment: Thanks for this nice solution  , could you please renew the link  of the page because it's broken

Comment: @user373141 The link is to another page on this site (Math Stack Exchange) and appears to still be working for me.

Comment: Unfortunately,  i got ( page is not found)

Comment: @user373141:  The link is to an Answer to a Question which has since been deleted.  This accounts for your inability to see the post, but once you reach 10K reputation, you will be able to see it.  As best I can see the Answer is cut and pasted above by its author, omegadot.  So there's little loss.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. Observe that by partial fraction decomposition one gets
$$
\frac6{n(n+3)}=\frac2{n}-\frac2{n+3}
$$ giving by [telescoping terms](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TelescopingSum.html)

> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^N\frac6{n(n+3)}=\frac{11}3-\frac2{N+1}-\frac2{N+2}-\frac2{N+3}
> $$

this yields both *convergence* of the given series and a *closed form* for its sum.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I am confused on the specifics of the telescoping terms. I know it doesn't matter for the final answer since n goes to infinity anyway, but when I write a few terms out it seems that I am getting $\frac {11} 3 -{2 \over N+3}-{2 \over N+4}-{2 \over N+5}$. What did I do wrong?

Comment: @dumbitdownjr No really, my above identity is correct as you can see by writing $$\frac2{n}-\frac2{n+3}=\Big(\frac2{n}-\frac2{n+1}\Big)+\Big(\frac2{n+1}-\frac2{n+2}\Big) +\Big(\frac2{n+2}-\frac2{n+3}\Big).$$ Hope you see it better now.

Comment: I see that they are equal, but I suppose I am thinking about the original sum before the partial fractions which shouldn't be different, but I think the n+3 in the denominator is throwing me off. I will keep thinking about it.

Comment: *Not really (I meant above)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

To find the sum, rewrite the general term as follows:
$$\frac 6{n(n+3)}=\frac 2n-\frac2{n+3}$$
You obtain a telescoping sum for each group of 4 terms, so you can find a closed form for the partial sums.